# Troubling shooting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Hi friends i'm doing my final year project for semantic similarity between sentences.
so i'm using word-net 2.1 database to retrieve the meaning. Each line i have to split no of words. In each word i'm get meaning and storing into array. But it can be get only meaning of  first sentences.

```
 String[] sentences = result.split("[\\.\\!\\?]");
 for (int i=0;i<sentences.length;i++)
             {  
                 System.out.println(i);
              System.out.println(sentences[i]);
              int wcount1 = sentences[i].split("\\s+").length;
              System.out.println(wcount1);int wcount1=wordCount(w2);
            System.out.println(wcount1);
        String[] word1 = sentences[i].split(" ");
        for (int j=0;j<wcount1;j++){  
            System.out.println(j);

         System.out.println(word1[j]);
     }
          }

         IndexWordSet set = wordnet.lookupAllIndexWords(word1[j]); 
         System.out.println(set);
         IndexWord[] ws = set.getIndexWordArray(); 

         **POS p = ws[0].getPOS();///line no 103**

         Set<String> synonyms = new HashSet<String>();
         IndexWord indexWord = wordnet.lookupIndexWord(p, word1[j]);
         Synset[] synSets = indexWord.getSenses();
         for (Synset synset : synSets)
         {
            Word[] words = synset.getWords();

            for (Word word : words)
            {
               synonyms.add(word.getLemma());
            }
         }
         System.out.println(synonyms);
```

OUTPUT:
only the `sentences[o]`(first sentence word's only shoe the meaning ...all the other words are not looping...)
it show this error..

```
**java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at first_JWNL.main(first_JWNL.java:102)**
```

Comment: Your question appears to be incomplete. Can you please revise? Also, what line are you getting the error in?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the variable `wcount1`, you assign in the value: `sentences[i].split("\\s+")..`. And yet, when you assign the variable `word1`, it is assigned with `sentences[i].split(" ")`.

Is it possible, because you are using two regular expressions, the second split (which is being assigned to the `word1` variable) is not splitting correctly? And hence when you access the value (`System.out.println(word1[j]);`), it is throwing the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Since the value of `wcount1` may be bigger than the length of `word1`.